# If I am allowing users to vote if only they are registered users... what other problems could arise?

Tags: database-design, voting

Suppose I am allowing users to vote only if they are registered users. 
I should limit each user to vote only once per article?
I should maintain a table with 4 columns - articleid, userid, bit (to indicate positive/negative) and a datetime column.

Do you still see this being abused?

to obtain net rating, I would query the table twice - once to count all votes that are positive and once to count all votes that are negative.

Please tell me any flaws/optimizations in my approach that you see.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the context...

Comment: SO has a number of other optimizations, like inhibiting changes voting changes after a certain period of time elapses...What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This seems to be DB Table Design. Add tags related to DB

Comment: SO inhibits voting changes?
basically, if I write an article, I want people to vote for/against it, but I want to make sure the voting does not get abused

Comment: You may find SO's datamodel useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678 Technical explanation here: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema

Comment: definition of abuse would be a user voting multiple times through using means such as spoofing ip address. An automated voter would be abuse on a much bigger scale.

Comment: I also appreciate posting SO's data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping voting to registered users avoids abuse, revoting through different IP adresses.

To obtain the net rating, you query the table once, to sum all the votes, or better yet, you keep a tally on each item of the final vote. Voting once means you increment or decrement the rating of the item.

EDIT: I must insist that querying multiple tables is bad practice if you can pre-calculate it. Breaking up relational models is a big part of database optimisation.

Comment: ah I see.  So I look at my table only when a user votes to make sure s/he has not voted for this article earlier, does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes. That way when you print out your list of articles you don't need to scan your entire votes table just to count everything.

I'm pretty sure SO also has a USER table with TotalUpVotes and TotalDownVotes columns done the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting voting to registered users is the way to go to avoid possible abuse. However once a user has voted you may want to think about whether they can undo their vote. I'm sure that won't happen often but something to think about.

BTW, you won't need to query the database twice as you could get the two values through a group by query, like so:

```
SELECT Vote, COUNT(Vote)
FROM tVotes
GROUP BY Vote, ArticleID
HAVING ArticleID = 1
```